# Iterate on a vector of promise in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, promise

I'm quite new to C++ multithreading and I'm trying to handle a vector of promise but when I do this thing at the end of main:

```
  for (promise<bool> pr : vect){
        pr.get_future().get();
    }
```

the compiler gives me an error.
How should I iterate in this vector?

Comment: Can you please give some more context? Preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, *what* error? Please include the actual (complete and unedited) error log as well in your question.

Comment: *"the compiler gives me an error"*? Well that means you've to look at line 46, there lies the problem.

Comment: _"the compiler gives me an error"_ What thought process led you to believe that this would be a sufficient description of your problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::promise` is not copyable, and your range-based for is trying to make copies of the vector members. You need to use a reference when iterating in this way:

```
for (promise<bool>& pr : vect) { ... }
```